# Optimizing VBA macro with Do While

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, do-while

I have an excel file with a LOT of worksheets, and i wanted to run a macro that would hide a range of rows based on the value at the top of this range.
My macro works, but since i have a ton or worksheets, it is taking forever to run...

Can somebody help me in optimizing it, because i may have done things unorthox-ly...

```
Sub MasquerPrix()

Dim RowNum As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim ColNum As Long

Columns("D:H").Select
Range("F1").Activate
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("E:F").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("A1").Select
        
StartRow = 1
RowNum = 1
ColNum = 2

    Do While Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value <> "Prix  Total (Public HT)"
        If Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value <> "Prix  Total (Public HT)" Then
            Rows(RowNum).Resize(12).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows(StartRow & ":" & (RowNum)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks a million !

Comment: You can use `Application.Match()` instead `Do ... Loop` for value searching . I also recommend that you pay attention to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I'll try that thanks

Comment: I tried using Application.Match, but i am new to VBA and i cannot quite figure out how to use an If function after it so it takes the value it matched and format its cell... Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Okay, i did it, thanks a lot, my boss is impressed thanks to you...

Answer (score 0):

Not having the raw data and not understanding the logic of its processing, sketched a version of the procedure using `Application.Match()` instead of `Do ... Loop`

```
Sub MasquerPrix()   'processes ActiveSheet
    Const STR_TO_MATCH = "Prix  Total (Public HT)", COL_NUM = 2
    Dim RowNum As Long, StartRow As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Columns("D:H").Hidden = False
    Columns("E:F").Hidden = True
            
    StartRow = 1

    RowNum = Application.Match(STR_TO_MATCH, Columns(COL_NUM), 0)
    If IsNumeric(RowNum) Then
        Rows(RowNum).Resize(12).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows(StartRow & ":" & RowNum).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Now that you are here, would you know if it's possible to CTRL-F and replace command buttons values all at once? I have like a billion of them and i want to change their text without having to modify them one by one...

Comment: @MaximilienOllier I have not heard of such a built-in feature